# Likening an amount of something to something else

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know how to express that, for example an amount of comments received on a paper is so big that it could've been an essay/that it looks/seems like an essay.

I got an essay worthy amount of comments? I got an essay's worth of comments?

I would appreciate if you could offer natural ways of expressing this.

Comment: My paper received **pages** of comments.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+book-worthy+writer%22&sxsrf=ALeKk032HbvJGg0z02poKzIjOtfc0c_LrA:1589455928420&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWmv_foLPpAhWFlFwKHUGsAngQ6wYIMA) are a few references to ***a book-worthy writer*** (someone considered a sufficiently good writer that they could be published in books). It's a little "unusual", and I don't see any real problem with either that or ***essay-worthy comments*** (or *an essay-worthy **amount** of comments*, both are fine). But I'd definitely say that hyphen is essential.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: An ***X's worth of Y's*** just means there's a sufficient ***quantity*** of Y's to require / justify an X, but we need ***X-worthy Y's*** to be sure they're of sufficient ***quality***.

Comment: 'A bookful of comments'. 'Reams of comments.' (Neither would be taken as intended literally/precisely.) These things are called _fuzzy quantifiers_ (eg 'a shedload of').

Comment: @FF Where does OP mention that quality is intended? The _-worthy_ is put as a suggested way of answering their question (one that doesn't work). Not an irrelevant comment, except that it's addressed incorrectly.